# Best way to Query Multiple APIs to add to one DataSet in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, api, try-catch

I am building a program to collect timeseries data from various APIs. If I search "GDP", a few of the APIs will return relevant timeseries IDs for the searched item. What is the best way to collect and aggregate data from multiple APIs? Right now I have:

```
try:
    df = df[['id', 'title']] #API 1 result
    r = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(requests.get(####).json()['response']) #API 2 result
    df = df.append(r)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The issue is that if API 1 doesnt return anything, then the exception is triggered.

There must be a way to do this using functions for each API and maybe wrapping those in a try statement?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution to my issue as seen below

```
data = pd.DataFrame()

def api_search1(search):
    #get pandas dataframe
    return data1

def api_search2(search):
    #get pandas dataframe
    return data2

func_list = [api_search1, api_search2]

for i in func_list:
    try:
        x = i(search)
        data = data.append(x)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Do you loop though the code with a while or for loop? If you do you can try putting a pass statement under the print(e) Exception handler. You should still get the exception error printed out, but the code should keep going to the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it helped me come to a solution!